# Where to define the postactivate hook with virtualenvwrapper-win?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using virtualenvwrapper-win and want to use the [postactivate hook](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts.html?highlight=postactivate#postactivate) of virtualenvwrapper to set environment variables. However it seems virtualenvwrapper-win doesn't include a postactivate file, and I haven't been able to get it to work by creating my own. Does anybody know how to get the postactivate hook to work with virtualenvwrapper-win?

I want to include this in postactivate to set an environment variable: `SET APP_SETTINGS="example.setting"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually solved it myself. You can put any environment variables in the activate.bat file in the Scripts folder of your virtualenv.

Comment: A problem might be that the moment you deactivate the environment, if you do not clean up those variables, they will remain in the parent session/console. In short they will leak outside of the environment. So probably an "unset" command must should be placed in deactivate.bat.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already defined your `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR` variable, just add this line to `workon.bat`.

```
call "%VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR%\postactivate.bat"
```

Just make sure you put it above `:END`