# How to enable virtual env using virtualenvwrapper-win module in jupyter?

Tags: python, batch-file, virtualenv, jupyter, virtualenvwrapper

Following this answer: [Where to define the postactivate hook with virtualenvwrapper-win?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536538/where-to-define-the-postactivate-hook-with-virtualenvwrapper-win) I set my access keys from twitter api in `activate.bat`. I added those keys at the end of that file.

When I call `env` on cmd it shows my keys, but Jupyter doesn't using `os.getenv('KEY')`. Instead, it prints `None`.

This is the code from activate.bat, which it is created by `virtualenvwrapper-win` using `mkvirtualenv <name>` command. At the end, I added access keys:

*(I'll write the complete code in order to know if I had added the keys in the right place)*

```
@echo off
set "VIRTUAL_ENV=C:\Users\rtormenta\Envs\twitter-example"
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT (
    set "PROMPT=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT%"
) else (
    if not defined PROMPT (
        set "PROMPT=$P$G"
    )
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=%PROMPT%"
)
set "PROMPT=(twitter-example) %PROMPT%"
REM Don't use () to avoid problems with them in %PATH%
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME goto ENDIFVHOME
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONHOME%"
:ENDIFVHOME
set PYTHONHOME=
REM if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH (
if not defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH1
    set "PATH=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH1
REM ) else (
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH2
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=%PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH2
set "PATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts;%PATH%"
:: In case user makes changes to PYTHONPATH
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONPATH (
    set "PYTHONPATH=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONPATH%"
) else (
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%"
)
set ACCESS_TOKEN=access
set ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=access_secret
set CONSUMER_KEY=c_key
set CONSUMER_SECRET=c_secret
```

In order to create those variables using `virtualenvwrapper-win` and `os.getenv()` in Jupyter, how can I set them using this method?